# Column header format in Python

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I want to have the column headers: `t1`, `sigma`, `P_calc`, `Vel` only at the very top, not before every step. The current output is attached.

```
import csv 
import InvasionC

with open('Data.csv', 'w') as f:
    for x in range(0,len(InvasionC.t1)):
        #print(Pe.Pe[x])      
        print(InvasionC.Isigma)  #for pressure
        print(InvasionC.IX)  #for velocity
        print(InvasionC.IVelprof)
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['t1', 'sigma', 'P_calc', 'Vel'])
        writer.writerows(zip([InvasionC.t1[x]],[InvasionC.Isigma[x]],[InvasionC.IX[x]],[InvasionC.IVelprof[x]]))
```

The current output is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5bBn.png)

Comment: You line `writer.writerow(['t1', 'sigma', 'P_calc', 'Vel'])` is repeated for every iteration, therefore, it's only lofic it appears multiple times. Just move it onne line before your `for`block starts and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first line is a heading, try using an indexed fetch for constraints, like this

```
import csv 
import InvasionC

with open('Data.csv', 'w') as f:
    for x in range(0,len(InvasionC.t1)):
        
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        line = zip([InvasionC.t1[x]],[InvasionC.Isigma[x]],[InvasionC.IX[x]],[InvasionC.IVelprof[x]]) if x else ['t1', 'sigma', 'P_calc', 'Vel']
        writer.writerow(line)
```